# ngIf not working with ng-template

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to show or hide a template based on the boolean value in Angular 4. Below are the HTML and code

--- This is inside Home.Component.HTML

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="isSummaryViewVisbile" #pricebookView ></ng-template>
```

---- This is inside HomeComponent

```
   isSummaryViewVisbile: boolean = true;
```

Above code doesn't work, it always hides template although I'm assigning true.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have `isSummaryViewVisbile`, are you sure one or the other isn't named `isSummaryViewVisible` (notice the correct spelling of 'visible')

Comment: I'm sorry, spelling is incorrect but it is same in both files.

Comment: Why are you not using `<ng-container>` which was introduced for exactly this purpose?

Comment: Here is a plunker. I have copied your code it works fine. https://plnkr.co/edit/6hbe0Z?p=preview

Answer (score 11):

The ng-template is an Angular element for rendering HTML. It is never displayed directly. In fact, before rendering the view, Angular replaces the  and its contents with a comment.If there is no structural directive and you merely wrap some elements in a ng-template, those elements disappear.

```
<p>Hip!</p>
<ng-template>
  <p>Hip!</p> //would disappear
</ng-template>
<p>Hooray!</p>
```

So the following code would work fine

```
isSummaryViewVisbile = true;

<ng-template [ngIf]="isSummaryViewVisbile" #pricebookView >
       Hello world.
</ng-template>
```

But if you replace [ngIf] with *ngIf, same code would not work.

Because Internally, Angular translates the *ngIf attribute into a ng-template element, wrapped around the host element. For example

```
<ng-template *ngIf="isSummaryViewVisbile" #pricebookView >
       Hello world.
</ng-template>
```

Would be converted to-

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="isSummaryViewVisbile">
      <ng-template #pricebookView >
           Hello world.
    </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

Now as we can see inner ng-template will always hide it's content.I hope this makes clear.

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/yB7PKx?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

As per Mohit's answer/comment your code is valid... if you were to assign content to the ng-template tag it should show.